# Why does a 403 error suddenly occurs?

Tags: java, linkedin-api, http-status-code-403, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social to get some informations via the LinkedIn API. Everything works fine : I can connect to my application using LinkedIn, I can recover some granted informations about my connections...
However, sometimes, I can't access anymore to LinkedIn and get this error :

```
16:28:00,741 WARN  [RestTemplate] GET request for "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=FNXqbb779g:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry,distance,relation-to-viewer,current-share,num-connections,num-connections-capped,summary,specialties,proposal-comments,associations,honors,interests,positions,publications,patents,languages,skills,certifications,educations,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,num-recommenders,recommendations-received,phone-numbers,im-accounts,twitter-accounts,date-of-birth,main-address,member-url-resources,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request:(url),api-public-profile-request:(url),site-public-profile-request:(url),api-standard-profile-request,public-profile-url)?format=json" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler
```

According to the error message, I'm not authorized to get the required informations (despite the fact that one minute before, I could access them).

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either your session token is getting expired or you're probably running into throttle limits. A session token is valid for some duration, you may need to check logs and see whether you are getting something like

> "Your session has expired and the post data is lost. Please
>   re-authenticate and re-post the data"

Also check about throttle limits here:
https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits

Comment: I'm gonna check that, I'll let you know if I find an answer.*

Comment: Well, according to LinkedIn, I'm way below my throttle limit. I didn't find informations about expired session either (I tried logging out and in again, didn't change something).

Comment: By "session token" Juned probably means "access token". LinkedIn's documentation says their access tokens last 60 days: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication Check this page's "Refreshing an access token" information for how to get a fresh access token when the one you have expires: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens